# Podsでライブラリをインストールすれどもimportできず

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Socket.IO-Client-Swift というライブラリを使ってプログラムを書こうとしています。
XcodeでNew ProjectをSwiftで新規作成し、Podfileをプロジェクトフォルダに作成しました。

[Podfileファイル]

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 1.1'
```

を作成し、

```
pod install
```

で成功。

AppDelegate.swiftにて

```
import Socket_IO_Client_Swift
```

を行ったところ、
/（省略）/AppDelegate.swift:10:8: No such module 'Socket_IO_Client_Swift'

のエラー発生。CocoaPodsを使うのは初めてということもあり、対処の方法がわかりません。おそらく基本的なことで間違っているのだと思いますが、対処方法ご存知の方、ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.IO-Client-Swiftのバージョン1.xはSwift 1.2に対応していないので、フレームワークのビルドに失敗していると思われます。

バージョンを2以上に指定するか、下記のようにバージョンの指定を無くして、再度やってみてください。

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
```

コメントのやりとりによると、再インストールしても結果が変わっていないようですので、念のため`.xcworkspace`ファイルと`Podfile.lock`、および`Pods`フォルダを削除してからもう一度`pod install`コマンドを実行して再インストールしてみてください。

Comment: 再度、プロジェクトを作成しバージョンアップを2.4.2以上でpodlike
を作成してからimportすると問題なく動きました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

**CocoaPods**

```
pod --version

0.38.2
```

**Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 2.4.2'
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
 import Socket_IO_Client_Swift
```

https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/blob/master/README.md

CocoaPodsを使った場合は `.xcworkspace`から作業を始めるようにして下さい。

私の場合はこれで問題なく動作しました。

Comment: $ pod --version　　
0.38.2　　
Podfileを書き直して再インストールしました。
.xcworkspaceから開くを行っております。
XCode Version 6.4です。
何故エラーが出るのか不思議です。

Comment: 色々と触ったところ原因はわかりませんが、AppDelegate.swiftのimport Socket_IO_Client_Swift追加のエラーは無くなりましたが、ViewController.swiftのimport Socket_IO_Client_Swift追加はエラー(/(省略)/ViewController.swift:10:8: No such module 'Socket_IO_Client_Swift')が発生します。何かにリンク付けしなければならないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

こちら拝見いたしますと，import方法が変わっていますね．

```
import SocketIOClientSwift
```

にするとエラーが消え，無事動作しました．